# How to make a block that out of container act like it inside container?

Tags: html, css

Please look at [example](https://codepen.io/hihihi05/pen/qBrBbKr) for better understanding because I am poor at English)

I need left-block to has the same margin-left as container and right-block to has width to the right side of screen. For screen less than 1600(container width) I will apply media. So I applied these styles

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 400px;
}
.left {
  width: 35vw;
  max-width: 522px;
  margin-left: calc(35vw - 522px);
  background: red;
}
.right {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Problem: on 1920 screen it looks ok but if i reduce screen from 1920 to 1600 left-block's margin-left is not the same as container's.

Question: what should I do to left-block so it has the same margin as container's?

Comment: Can you clarify something? Is the parent container supposed to match the width of the container element?

Comment: It is supposed to be that block with class="left" has the same margin-left as element with class="container" from 1920 to 1600 screen. Left block inside parent has 522px width but it doesn't matter

Comment: First of all my issue is margin-left

Comment: Okay, but why use vw then? Because vw is a calculation of the view width, so it's going to collapse, and your container class has a margin: 0 auto; so they won't be the same as your left margin on the left element.

Comment: Ok. So what is the best solution for this issue?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean you want the container element to match to be aligned with the green left element, even while collapsing from 1920 to 1600, correct?

Comment: yes it is. Only left element is red)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try to use CSS on body:

```css
/* ADDED */
    @media (min-width:1600px){
      body{
        padding-left:  calc(35vw - 522px);
      }
    }
```

### DEMO

```css
.container {
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 400px;
}
.left {
  width: 35vw;
  max-width: 522px;
  /*margin-left: calc(35vw - 522px);*/
  background: red;
}
.right {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
/* ADDED */
@media (min-width:1600px){
  body{
    padding-left:  calc(35vw - 522px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer right here for what you're looking for @Ivan01

Comment: Thank you @MaxiGui this is what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is one [decision](https://codepen.io/IIIu6ko/pen/rNyNWbp) I has just found. But in this case body is added with overflow-x: hidden because 100vw did not take into account the scroll width so it appears

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 1600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 400px;
}
.left {
  width: 35vw;
  max-width: 522px;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```